# How to deal with attacks on Zend Framework web site? site currently down

Tags: php, security, lamp

This is my first question on this "forum" please be indulgent with me if my questions are somewhat too simplistic for you. i joined this community in order to improve myself and help others.Thank you.

I received a mail from my hosting company saying the `Zend Framework 1.10.8` site that am responsible for (the first one that i developed myself)  is been hacked. so the moved the content of `public_html` to `public_html_hacked` . someone actually managed to upload 2 php files `db5.php` `sys.php`. I need to get the site back up.

The only thing i managed to do is to change the cpanel password. I've changed the public_html permission to 754 but i think that's not going to work.

Please give me advice, best pratices and guidance. Thank you for reading this

Answer (score 2):

The responses to your question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701411/protecting-a-zend-framework-site-from-hacking) are pretty much correct, you need to either [prevent executable files being uploaded](http://www.blog.highub.com/apache/http-server/apache-htaccess-prevent-users-from-uploading-and-executing-files/) to your site or [prevent uploaded files from executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618908/how-to-prevent-a-specific-directory-from-running-php-html-and-javascript-langu), perhaps both.

I don't have enough experience with Zend to give you good advice about hardening, beyond the above. I suggest that the [Zend forum](http://forums.zend.com/) is the best place to find further information on that subject.

Comment: notes taken very seriously, will get back when i get something working. thanks for the response.very much appreciated